# How to use VersionPress to clone across servers?

Tags: wordpress, git

I would like to clone a WordPress site that is already in VersionPress to a new server.

The instructions are generally only listed for cloning on the current server. I have one server dedicated to Dev and another for Production

I tried the following command line:

```
wp vp clone 
    --name=sitename 
    --ssh=username@site.school.edu
    --path=/var/www/html/folder 
    --url=https://site.school.edu/destination 
    --dbname=mydb 
    --dbuser=myuser 
    --dbpass=mypass 
    --dbhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
    --dbprefix=wp- 
    --force
```

However after I login to the remote ssh server, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /var/www/html/atwiki/wp-includes/load.php on line 317
Error: Cannot connect over SSH using provided configuration.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](https://blog.versionpress.net/2016/11/remote-workflows/) on how to achieve that today. We will have a more polished way in the future.